# Share Postfix IMAP Calenders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, imap

We are currently running a dovecot mailserver(maildir) and postfix. - Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Our new COO wants to sync his contacts and calendar with outlook(MAC) and iOS(iPhone) using our service.

Is there a way we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP doesn't handle calendars or contacts. What you want is carddav and caldav. There are many solutions for that out there.

Comment: And before you ask, product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Thank you, will have a look